# Windows message with 0x3B code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, .net-4.0

While logging off in Windows XP the system is sending the message with code 0x3B to the main window of the application. It was received together with 0x11 WM_QUERYENDSESSION message. Here is the log of incoming messages for WndProc:

```
Message processing: Id = 0x3B, wParam = -2147483637, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processing: Id = 0x11, wParam = 0, lParam = -2147483648, result = 0
Form closing event handler. Reason:WindowsShutDown
Message processed: Id = 0x11, wParam = 0, lParam = -2147483648, result = 1
Message processed: Id = 0x3B, wParam = -2147483637, lParam = 0, result = 1
Message processing: Id = 0x3B, wParam = -2147483639, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processing: Id = 0x16, wParam = 1, lParam = -2147483648, result = 0
Form closed event handler. Reason:WindowsShutDown
Message processing: Id = 0x46, wParam = 0, lParam = 1239312, result = 0
Message processed: Id = 0x46, wParam = 0, lParam = 1239312, result = 0
Message processing: Id = 0x47, wParam = 0, lParam = 1239312, result = 0
Message processed: Id = 0x47, wParam = 0, lParam = 1239312, result = 0
Message processing: Id = 0x86, wParam = 0, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processing: Id = 0x7F, wParam = 2, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processed: Id = 0x7F, wParam = 2, lParam = 0, result = 852077
Message processing: Id = 0x7F, wParam = 2, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processed: Id = 0x7F, wParam = 2, lParam = 0, result = 852077
Message processed: Id = 0x86, wParam = 0, lParam = 0, result = 1
Message processing: Id = 0x6, wParam = 0, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processed: Id = 0x6, wParam = 0, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processing: Id = 0x1C, wParam = 0, lParam = 2620, result = 0
Message processed: Id = 0x1C, wParam = 0, lParam = 2620, result = 0
Message processing: Id = 0x8, wParam = 0, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processed: Id = 0x8, wParam = 0, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processing: Id = 0x2, wParam = 0, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processed: Id = 0x2, wParam = 0, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processing: Id = 0x82, wParam = 0, lParam = 0, result = 0
Message processed: Id = 0x82, wParam = 0, lParam = 0, result = 0
```

My application has a bug in Windows XP during logging off. It doesn't close. And the reason is:

```
Message processed: Id = 0x3B, wParam = -2147483637, lParam = 0, result = <b>3</b>
```

instead of **1**

Any ideas what does this message mean? And why is it processed incorrectly?

Comment: Show us the message processing code? especially for the close one?

Comment: @Scott: this question is very related to programming, even if it could be better asked (for example, some sample code would be helpful).

Comment: It is WM_INITENDSESSION, otherwise undocumented.  Be sure it gets passed to DefWindowProc() or you'll indeed have shutdown problems.

Comment: My application doesn't override this message processing by default. It also doesn't have any other child forms except of the main one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Google-fu reveals this to be an undocumented message - WM_CLIENTSHUTDOWN.  [This](http://doxygen.reactos.org/da/d74/subsystems_2win32_2win32k_2ntuser_2defwnd_8c_source.html) may be of interest, but all it does is send WM_QUERYENDSESSION / WM_ENDSESSION to the window and its children.  The return value of 3 (MCSR_DONOTSHUTDOWN) indicates that the window, or one of its children, is vetoing the request.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description and the links.